# Vertices duplication elimination in models

Tags: c++, opengl, hash

When importing a model in .obj format a lot of the polygons share vertices and thus consume memory in vain, what I want to do is remove the duplicates by only saving unique vertices.

**Hashing of Vertex**

```
/// Template specialization for hashing of a Vec3
namespace std {
template<typename T>
struct hash<Vec3<T>> {
    void hash_combine(size_t &seed, const size_t &hash) const {
        seed ^= hash + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
    }

    size_t operator() (const Vec3<T> &vec) const {
        auto hasher = hash<float>{};
        auto hashed_x = hasher(vertex.position.x);
        auto hashed_y = hasher(vertex.position.y);
        auto hashed_z = hasher(vertex.position.z);
        auto hashed_color_r = hasher(vertex.color.r);
        auto hashed_color_g = hasher(vertex.color.g);
        auto hashed_color_b = hasher(vertex.color.b);
        auto hashed_color_a = hasher(vertex.color.a);
        auto hashed_texcoord_x = hasher(vertex.texCoord.x);
        auto hashed_texcoord_y = hasher(vertex.texCoord.y);
        auto hashed_normal_x = hasher(vertex.normal.x);
        auto hashed_normal_y = hasher(vertex.normal.y);
        auto hashed_normal_z = hasher(vertex.normal.z);

        size_t seed = 0;
        hash_combine(seed, hashed_x);
        hash_combine(seed, hashed_y);
        hash_combine(seed, hashed_z);
        hash_combine(seed, hashed_texcoord_x);
        hash_combine(seed, hashed_texcoord_y);
        hash_combine(seed, hashed_normal_x);
        hash_combine(seed, hashed_normal_y);
        hash_combine(seed, hashed_normal_z);
        return seed;
    }
};
}
```

**Importing mesh with tinyobjcloader**

```
Mesh Renderer::load_mesh_from_file(std::string filepath) {
tinyobj::attrib_t attrib;
std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t> shapes;
std::vector<tinyobj::material_t> materials;
std::string err;
auto success = tinyobj::LoadObj(&attrib, &shapes, &materials, &err, filepath.c_str());
if (!success) { SDL_Log("Failed loading mesh %s: %s", filepath.c_str(), err.c_str()); return Mesh(); }

std::unordered_map<Vertex<float>, size_t> unique_vertices{};
Mesh mesh{};
for (auto shape : shapes) { // Shapes
    size_t index_offset = 0;
    for (auto face : shape.mesh.num_face_vertices) { // Faces (polygon)
        for (auto v = 0; v < face; v++) {
            tinyobj::index_t idx = shape.mesh.indices[index_offset + v];
            Vertex<float> vertex{};
            float vx = attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 0];
            float vy = attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 1];
            float vz = attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 2];
            vertex.position = {vx, vy, vz};

            float tx = attrib.vertices[3 * idx.texcoord_index + 0];
            float ty = attrib.vertices[3 * idx.texcoord_index + 1];
            vertex.texCoord = {tx, ty};

            float nx = attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 0];
            float ny = attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 1];
            float nz = attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 2];
            vertex.normal = {nx, ny, nz};

            // These two lines work just fine (includes all vertices)
            // mesh.vertices.push_back(vertex);
            // mesh.indices.push_back(mesh.indices.size());

            // Check for unique vertices, models will contain duplicates
            if (unique_vertices.count(vertex) == 0) {
                unique_vertices[vertex] = mesh.indices.size();
                mesh.vertices.push_back(vertex);
                mesh.indices.push_back(mesh.indices.size());
            } else {
                mesh.indices.push_back(unique_vertices.at(vertex));
            }
        }
        index_offset += face;
    }
}

SDL_Log("Number of vertices: %lu for model %s", mesh.vertices.size(), filepath.c_str());
return mesh;
}
```

The first image is when all the vertices are included.

[image]

This one is when I am only using unique vertices.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (unique_vertices.count(vertex) == 0) {

unique_vertices[vertex] = mesh.**vertices**.size();

mesh.indices.push_back(mesh.**vertices**.size());

mesh.vertices.push_back(vertex);

}

Explanation: indices are "pointers" to vertex locations. For that you need to get index where you write vertex data and not index for index data.

Comment: Yup! This was the problem after all this time! No wonder it worked without the check since the indices was always in order (0, 1, 2, ..., n).

Answer (score 1):

From the shown images, it seems to be a triangle-vertex reference problem.

Normally, [obj format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/) collects a list of unique vertices and each triangle is just a set of three indices corresponding to its three vertices. Let us assume that, for some reason, you do have a repetition of vertex A and vertex B and you decide to eliminate vertex B. In  this case, you need to modify the references of all triangles containing B and substitute them with A.

Comment: Hmm.. I can't find anything in the spec that says that the vertices are *required* to be unique. :/

Comment: They are not, but a sensible mesh creator would not put repetitions(if you have repetitions, the redundancy occupies more space than necessary). However, this can happen, for example if your mesh is converted from al STL file, which does have repetitions.

Comment: @Entalpi Is it possible that your mesh has same vertex xyz but different texCoord. Some textures may have coordinates jumping in a vertex that requires repeating same coordinate with different texture coordinates. But that should be rare and it shouldn't explain the difference in rendering that you get. Only coding error that I can see is when you read the texture v coordinate that is copy-paste from u coordinate.

Comment: @PauliNieminen Thanks for spotting that error! Will fix it, gotta update the answer too since I have changed some things which might have caused the problem (but probably did not since the problem still exists..)

Answer (score -1):

Its not good idea to eliminate repeated coordinates. Coordinates will repeat for example in the  stitching areas between meshes to form a closed 3D mesh structure. In 3D gaming, low polygon mesh structure is adopted to allow fast rendering, but unless otherwise , dealing with a these point clouds is not longer a big issue as powerful GPU and multi-core CPUs system are making real life like animations possible nowadays.